# Group by dimensions and gather from wide to long with multiple metrics

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have data in the following format in Big Query:

| Year_Month | User_ID | Dim_1 | Dim_2 | Metric_1 | Metric_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-02 | a1 | cat | desktop | 1 | 34 |
| 2024-02 | a1 | dog | mobile | 1 | 23 |
| 2024-02 | a1 | dog | desktop | 1 | 12 |
| 2024-02 | a1 | mouse | tablet | 1 | 9 |

The real data I am working with has millions of User_IDs, 24 months of data and a lot of Dimenions and Metric columns that I don't need.

I would like to group by the Year_Month and the User_ID and then sum the metrics by the dimensions and convert from wide to long format. Serveral columns also need to be cleaned up in order to group values together. For instance in the sample data 'mobile' and 'tablet' should be treated as 'mobile'. Many of the columns I am working with need to be cleaned up like this.

Currently I have something like this that works for 1 metric but I need 2 or more metrics:

```
create table test_wide as 
(
select Year_Month,
User_ID,
sum(case when Dim_1 = 'cat' then Metric_1) end as Cat_m1,
sum(case when Dim_1 = 'dog' then Metric_1) end as Dog_m1,
sum(case when Dim_1 = 'mouse' then Metric_1) end as Mouse_m1,
sum(case when Dim_2 in ('mobile', 'tablet') then Metric_1) end as Mobile_m1,
sum(case when Dim_2  = 'desktop' then Metric_1) end as Desktop_m1
from data
group by 1,2
) 
;

/* Convert from wide to long */

SELECT Year_Month, User_ID,
    Dim, 
    SAFE_CAST(value AS int64) value
FROM (
    SELECT Year_Month, User_ID, 
      REGEXP_REPLACE(SPLIT(pair, ':')[OFFSET(0)], r'^"|"$', '') Dim, 
      REGEXP_REPLACE(SPLIT(pair, ':')[OFFSET(1)], r'^"|"$', '') Value 
    FROM test_wide t, 
    UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(to_json_string(t), r'{|}', ''))) pair
  )
  WHERE NOT LOWER(Dim) IN ('year_month', 'user_id')
  and SAFE_CAST(value AS int64) > 0
```

The output I am looking for is this:

| Year_Month | User_ID | Dimension | Metric_1 | Metric_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-02 | a1 | cat | 1 | 34 |
| 2024-02 | a1 | dog | 2 | 35 |
| 2024-02 | a1 | mouse | 1 | 9 |
| 2024-02 | a1 | desktop | 2 | 46 |
| 2024-02 | a1 | mobile | 2 | 32 |

The data needs to be in this long format to then be fed into a dashboarding tool. Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the query below, using the [UNPIVOT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unpivot_operator) operator:

```sql
WITH sample AS (
  SELECT "2024-02" as year_month, "a1" as user_id, "cat" as dim_1, "desktop" as dim_2, 1 as metric_1, 34 as metric_2 UNION ALL
  SELECT "2024-02" as year_month, "a1" as user_id, "dog" as dim_1, "mobile" as dim_2, 1 as metric_1, 23 as metric_2 UNION ALL
  SELECT "2024-02" as year_month, "a1" as user_id, "dog" as dim_1, "desktop" as dim_2, 1 as metric_1, 12 as metric_2 UNION ALL
  SELECT "2024-02" as year_month, "a1" as user_id, "mouse" as dim_1, "tablet" as dim_2, 1 as metric_1, 9 as metric_2
)
SELECT
  year_month,
  user_id,
  dimension,
  sum(metric_1) metric_1,
  sum(metric_2) metric_2
FROM sample
UNPIVOT(dimension FOR original_dim IN (dim_1, dim_2))
GROUP BY year_month, user_id, dimension
```

Output:
[image: Query output]